# NULL-pointer associated with vector

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, bounding-volume

In my ray tracer I am constructing a Bounding Volume Hierarchy. I have used a couple of days trying to fix this error but I seem to be doing something fundamentally wrong.

This first method is the construction being called is the one below using a typedef std::vector Objects array.

```
void BVH::build(Objects* objs)
{
    // construct the bounding volume hierarchy
    int size = objs->size();

    // Calculate the bounding box for this node
    BBox bb = (*objs)[0]->boundingBox();
    for ( int p = 1; p < size; p++ )
        bb.expandToInclude( (*objs)[p]->boundingBox());
    Vector3 pivot = (bb.max + bb.min) * 0.5f;
    tree.bbox = bb;

    int split = qsplit(objs, size, pivot.x, 0);

    tree.left = subdivision(objs, split, 1);
    tree.right = subdivision(&objs[split], size - split, 1);
}
```

This method is used by the one below to construct the leaf nodes in my binary tree.

```
Node* BVH::makeLeaf(Objects* objs, int num)
{
    Node* node = new Node;
    if ( num == 1 ) { node->objs = &objs[0]; }
    else if ( num == 2 ) { node->objs = ((&objs)[0],(&objs)[1]); }
    node->isLeaf = true;
    return node;
}
```

This is a recursive method using the array of Objects to split and construct nodes and leaf nodes.

```
Node* BVH::subdivision(Objects* objs, int size, int axis)
{
    if ( size == 1 ) { return makeLeaf(objs, 1); }
    if ( size == 2 ) { return makeLeaf(objs, 2); }

    Node* node = new Node;
    node->isLeaf = false;

    BBox bb = (*objs)[0]->boundingBox();
    for ( int p = 1; p < size; p++ )
        bb.expandToInclude((*objs)[p]->boundingBox());
    node->bbox = bb;
    Vector3 pivot = (bb.max + bb.min) * 0.5f;

    int split = qsplit(objs, size, pivot[axis], axis);

    node->left = subdivision(objs, split, (axis + 1) % 3);
    node->right = subdivision(&objs[split], size - split, (axis + 1) % 3);

    return node;
}
```

Running this code will give me an segmentation-fault inside subdivision.

Here's a post of the null pointer from gdb:

```
debug: Loading "teapot.obj"...
debug: Loaded "teapot.obj" with 576 triangles

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000040bb9e in BVH::subdivision (this=0x61f0c0, objs=0x61f100, size=5, axis=1) at BVH.cpp:44
44      BBox bb = (*objs)[0]->boundingBox();
(gdb) bt
0  0x000000000040bb9e in BVH::subdivision (this=0x61f0c0, objs=0x61f100, size=5, axis=1) at BVH.cpp:44
1  0x000000000040bdef in BVH::subdivision (this=0x61f0c0, objs=0x61f0a0, size=9, axis=0) at BVH.cpp:56
2  0x000000000040bd62 in BVH::subdivision (this=0x61f0c0, objs=0x61f0a0, size=18, axis=2) at BVH.cpp:53
3  0x000000000040bd62 in BVH::subdivision (this=0x61f0c0, objs=0x61f0a0, size=36, axis=1) at BVH.cpp:53
4  0x000000000040bd62 in BVH::subdivision (this=0x61f0c0, objs=0x61f0a0, size=72, axis=0) at BVH.cpp:53
5  0x000000000040bd62 in BVH::subdivision (this=0x61f0c0, objs=0x61f0a0, size=144, axis=2) at BVH.cpp:53
6  0x000000000040bd62 in BVH::subdivision (this=0x61f0c0, objs=0x61f0a0, size=288, axis=1) at BVH.cpp:53
7  0x000000000040b9ca in BVH::build (this=0x61f0c0, objs=0x61f0a0) at BVH.cpp:21
8  0x00000000004121ac in Scene::preCalc (this=0x61f0a0) at Scene.cpp:42
9  0x0000000000402fde in makeTeapotScene () at assignment1.cpp:113
10 0x000000000040f973 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe798) at main.cpp:65
(gdb) p (*objs)[0]
$1 = (Object *&) @0x0: <error reading variable>
```

Comment: Why are you using a *pointer* to a `vector`, and a `vector` that holds pointers, and why are you combining those two :) ?

Comment: Because the guy who made the framework defined this build function to receive this vector<Object*> which I totally agree is crazy, but never the less is what I have to deal with.

Comment: In the meantime, it may be worth using valgrind: gdb only catches the problems once it's definitely too late, valgrind may give  you valuable infos if you're accidentally accessing arrays out of bounds or similar things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(&objs)[0]
```

Is the same as

```
*(&objs)
```

which is the same as

```
objs
```

In the same way,

```
(&objs)[1]
```

is the same as

```
objs + 1
```

which is most likely *not* the address of a valid object.

The line

```
node->objs = ((&objs)[0],(&objs)[1]);
```

since it uses the comma operator, throws away the value of `(&objs)[0]` and sets `node->objs` to `objs + 1`, which is invalid.

It's unclear what you expect that assignment to accomplish, so I have no idea what you should replace it with.

Comment: After a talk with a friend of mine I replaced that piece of gode with:
    node->objs = new std::vector<Object*>;
    if ( num == 1 )
        node->objs->push_back((*objs)[0]); }
    else if ( num == 2 )
    {
        node->objs->push_back((*objs)[0]);
        node->objs->push_back((*objs)[1]);
    }

Comment: +1 for this answer. @miniwolf, you still have the same problem in at least one more place: `node->right = subdivision(&objs[split]...`

Answer (score 0):

After using many hours on this interesting typedef, I got help from a friend and we wrote an adapter method to turn

```
vector<Object*>* into vector<Object*>&
```

which gave every method a much cleaner and nicer look.

```
void BVH::build(Objects* objs_orig)
{
    m_objects = objs_orig;
    std::vector<Object*>* objs = objs_orig;
    return build(*objs);
}

void BVH::build(const std::vector<Object*>& objs)
{
    tree = makeTree(objs, 1);
}
```